# Need to pass Variable from Shell Action to Oozie Shell using Hive

Tags: shell, hive, oozie

All,

Looking to pass variable from shell action to the oozie shell. I am running commands such as this, in my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
evalDate="hive -e 'set hive.execution.engine=mr; select     max(cast(create_date as int)) from db.table;'"
evalPartition=$(eval $evalBaais)
echo "evaldate=$evalPartition"
```

Trick being that it is a hive command in the shell.

Then I am running this to get it in oozie:

```
${wf:actionData('getPartitions')['evaldate']}
```

But it pulls a blank every time! I can run those commands in my shell fine and it seems to work but oozie does not. Likewise, if I run the commands on the other boxes of the cluster, they run fine as well. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure if you can call a hive query from shell action. I would suggest you use hive action for the hive query and then pass the parameter which can be captured. Also don't forget to use <capture-output />

Comment: Um, I don't think you can save the output for the Hive action. From my research it seems you can for shell/ssh/java actions but Hive you cannot as it would write to disk. I had this action running similarly for Sqoop prior - why would it work for Sqoop and not for Hive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was configuration regarding to my cluster. When I ran as oozie user, I had write permission issues to /tmp/yarn. With that, I changed the command to run as:

baais="export HADOOP_USER_NAME=functionalid; hive yarn -hiveconf hive.execution.engine=mr -e 'select max(cast(create_date as int)) from db.table;'"

Where hive  allows me to run as yarn.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is to use "-S" switch in hive command for silent output. (see below)

Also, what is "evalBaais"? You might need to replace this with "evalDate". So your code should look like this -

```
#!/bin/sh
evalDate="hive -S -e 'set hive.execution.engine=mr; select            max(cast(create_date as int)) from db.table;'"
evalPartition=$(eval $evalDate)
echo "evaldate=$evalPartition"
```

Now you should be able to capture the out.